# Example code for getting task status WaitingForChildrenToComplete

Tags: c#, multithreading

Please give an example code for getting task status WaitingForChildrenToComplete.
I made an example as I was thinking, but it does not give the desired status.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            void MyMethod1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MyMethod1");
            }

            void MyMethod2(Task task)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MyMethod2");
                Task MyTask = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.WriteLine(task.Status); }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                MyTask.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);                
            }
            
            Task MyTask = null;
            MyTask = Task.Run(() => MyMethod2(MyTask));
            MyTask.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's impossible because it's a bug and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Task parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Task child = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(200),
                TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        });
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine($"Status: {parent.Status}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Status: WaitingForChildrenToComplete
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MM6bel).

The reason that your example doesn't work is because the `Task.Run` method is a shortcut for the `Task.Factory.StartNew` configured with the [`TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) option. You can read about this [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

**Note:** The example above is intended to be minimal, and so it doesn't follow best practices. Particularly the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method is not configured with a specific `scheduler`, which [is not recommended](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), and might produce [compiler warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008). Also be aware that the ["attach to parent"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/attached-and-detached-child-tasks) functionality is rarely used today. AFAIK it was deemed a suspicious pattern by Microsoft itself shortly after its introduction, and today many Microsoft engineers would be glad to go back in time and un-invent this feature, if traveling back in time was possible.